# RML - get max value

Tags: python, dom, odoo, rml

I need to get max value from a list (that I think should be created first somehow).

There is `sale.order` class / object, from which RML report is generated. It has one2many relation with `sale.order.line`, which has field (or column) `delay`. So I need to check every line that is in that order and return max `delay` value, which would indicate delivery time (like if all products would be delivered at same time).

So for example to get first `delay` value from first line I can right something like this:

```
<para>[[ o.order_line[0].delay ]]</para>
```

Or I can output all values like this:

```
<para>[[ repeatIn(o.order_line,'l') ]]</para>
```

And then try something like:

```
<para>[[ max(l.delay) ]]</para>
```

But I get error that float can't be iterated (because you need to use list here). What could I do to create list from those values and then get max value? Or maybe there is some other way to get max value in RML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [[ max([ln.delay for ln in o.order_line ]) ]]